# Mixing CodeIgniter, HTML, JQuery, and MySQL

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm still very new to PHP, JQuery, and MySQL and a current project I'm working on has me feeling like I'm probably going about it the worst way possible. I'd like to allow a user to perform some db operations in a CodeIgniter View but do so using JQuery. Here are the general details:

- My View has a table that is populated with data from a MySQL table.
- I'd like to allow users to be able to edit elements in the table
- I'll pass the updated data back to the controller, on to the model,
  update the table, and redirect it back to the view (The user will see
  the refresh, but I don't mind, and don't really want to add in AJAX
  to avoid this)

Current Implementation: 
(*I had to use a workaround for the argument being passed in to the javascript function because I had three sets of quotes in the table row echo. I know it's not elegant, but nothing else I tried worked.*)

```
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $javascript_filename = "\"" .$row->filename ."\"";
        echo "<tr>
              <td>" .$row->message_num ."</td>
              <td bgcolor='#f7f780'>Message not Recorded</td>
              <td>" .stripslashes($row->message_text) ."<button style='float:right' onclick='editMessageText(" .$javascript_filename .")'>edit</button></td>
        </tr>";
   }
```

*This is what it looks like after a user clicks the edit button and the editMessageText() function is called.*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbl14.jpg

My Questions:

1. How can I replace a td element in jquery, so that it's more like a spreadsheet for the user?
2. Is there a much better way of doing this than I currently am?
3. Where are the biggest shortcomings of this design?

Comment: you can try looking into Datatables, using server side processing, could be a simpler approach. Take a look at this: http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html

Comment: That is an AWESOME solution! I think I may go that route!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [Datatables.js](http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html) is provides functions for what you are looking for.

Just adding this as an answer for future reference.